# How to format hyperlink to select a radio button on my homepage?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, radio-button, selected

On my homepage (web form) I have 3 radio buttons to select from. How do I format a hyperlink to direct the user to that page and automatically select a radio button?

```
<div class="col-lg-3"> 
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbtnChoise" Font-Size="11"  ToolTip="Select a service: A description of the service is listed under each title once selected."  runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbtnChoise_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="G1"> OPTION 1</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="G2"> OPTION 2</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="G3"> OPTION 3</asp:ListItem>          
            </asp:RadioButtonList> </div>
```

I would like to set a hyperlink to automatically select the first radio button. I've tried by reading other questions like this one but none seem to work.

Let's say my webpage is: https://examplesite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, your problem is how to provide a link to a page, when a user navigate through that link will check the first radio button once rendered

If my understanding is correct

you can use js to achieve this

assuming you have jquery included

on your radio button page, add below

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var isCheck = getParameterByName("isCheckRadio") === 'true';

    if(isCheck){
        $('input:radio[name="rdbtnChoise"]').first().prop("checked", true);
    }
});

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
</script>
```

which means when page load, if the url has querystring `isCheckRadio` value as `true`, check first radio

then the url you provided will be something like

```
<a href="https://examplesite.com?isCheckRadio=true">link</a>
```

Comment: My webpage is a asp.net web form. Can I add js code in a default.aspx file? Or do I just create a new js file?

Comment: I created a .js file with your code and it still doesn't work. Is there anything I have to modify in your script? Also is this line of code correct? 

$('input:radio[name="rdbtnChoise"]').first().prop("checked", true); It says "name=" whereas my radiobuttonlist has an ID not a name.

Comment: @justinpees can you show relevant part of the render html (not asp .net webform the actual html source code)? and check if you see any error in browser console.  if I remember correctly, the id will be render as name for the input, so it should be correct.

Comment: There are no errors in browser console. I'm typing the url with querystring directly in browser instead of assigning it to a button.

Comment: I created a file called resetfield.js and placed it in my bin folder containing your script. Then I typed the url with querystring in browser and it led me to the page but the first radio was not checked.

Comment: Do you think it's because I have: OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbtnChoise_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" for the radio list?

Comment: should b okay, but remove it just for testing purpose. try add a alert into your resetfield.js to test if the js file loaded correctly